# Find heaviest path in grid like graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have an input graph of `N by N` edges, where each vertex has a certain weight to it
and each vertex `[i,j]` is connected only to `[i+1,j] and [i,j+1]`, meaning that each vertex is connected to the one on its right and the one above it.

heres an example of such a graph where `N=4`:
[example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vV2oK.png)

given this type of grid graph, what do you think is the fastest way to calculate the heaviest path in it?
(the one in which the summery of all vertices values in it is maximized)

Comment: What have **YOU** tried / researched so far? Share your ideas / findings / code.

Answer (score 0):

I know this problem on its opposite side, finding the shortest distance to travel from A to B inside a graph.

Popular algorithms for it are Dijkstra (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) and A* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) the latter being faster, but not computing necessarily the "optimal" way.

I'd bet that with some adjustments, you could tweak one of these algorithms to compute the opposite. Not 100% sure though, give it a shot a share your solution with us !

Comment: Yes, and Dijkstra can be simplified in this case due to the very oriented nature of this graph. Edges only go to the right or up, never going back, so if you update your vertices in the right order, you only need to update each vertex once.

Answer (score 0):

`dp[i][j]` will store the heaviest path which ends at `[i][j]`. Now since the only way to reach `[i][j]` is from `[i-1][j]` and `[i][j-1]` therefore
`dp[i][j] = max(dp[i-1][j], dp[i][j-1]) + arr[i][j]`. And the heaviest path is `max(dp[i][j])` for every vertex.